# Simplify propositional equation $\lnot (P\to Q) \iff (P \land \lnot Q)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've been asked to simplify the proposition below, I've done some working but don't think it's correct.

$\lnot (P\to Q) \iff  (P \land \lnot Q)$

$\lnot((\lnot P) \lor Q) \iff (P \land \lnot Q)$

$((\lnot\lnot P) \lor \lnot Q) \iff (P \land \lnot Q)$

$(P \lor \lnot Q) \iff (P \land \lnot Q)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$¬((¬P) ∨ Q) ⟺ (P ∧ ¬Q)\tag{2}$$

$$((¬¬P) \color{red}{∨} ¬Q) ⟺ (P ∧ ¬Q)\tag{$\color{red}\times$ 3}$$

Your move from step $2$ to step $3$ is incorrect. By Demorgans $\lnot(a\lor b) \equiv (\lnot a \land \lnot b).$

So we replace step $(3)$ with  $$(\lnot\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \iff (P \land \lnot Q)\tag{3*}$$

$$P \land \lnot Q \iff P \land \lnot Q\tag 4$$

$$\top \tag{Tautology, hence true, 5}$$

---

In the end, we see that $\lnot(P \to Q) \equiv (P \land \lnot Q)$, because we needed only to simplify the left hand side, to show that it is logically equivalent to the right hand side.

Tip: when in doubt, it never hurts to consult the [truth tables](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/) for the lhs, and rhs, respectively.

[image]

[image]

We see that $\lnot (P\to Q)$ is equivalent to $P\land \lnot Q$ under each and every truth-value assignment to P and Q.

Comment: Thank you, this explains a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, Jakarta!